# Any Suggestion of books or materials which covers the following topics

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

I'm recently studying an article titled "[Koszul Algebras and Their Syzygies](http://www.dima.unige.it/~conca/Articoli%20Conca%20PDF/PDF%20da%20rivista/(2014)%20Conca%20(LNM%20Levico)%20Koszul%20Algebras%20and%20Their%20Syzygies.pdf)" by Aldo Conca.

Here the author used terms like Betti Number, Graded Betti Number of a module, Poincare series, Differential Graded Algebra, and so on..
Actually I merely have a good concept about those things, I just know the basic definitions only.

So can any one please suggest any good book or materials which clarifies all these things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of you need can find in the book of Bruns and Herzog.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much...